# Skeleton Framework - 3 columns layout - Fails to reduce

Tags: css, responsive-design, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am tasked with the job of converting a 3 column site to a responsive design. I am using Skeleton framework and it renders correctly in a mobile (each column is stacked one below the other) and normally in a desktop. But it doesn't stack up in a tablet.

What I want is in a tablet (iPad) it has to show only 2 columns and the third column stacked below.

The page is here: https://49.207.177.87/articles/new.html

How can I modify the skeleton css to reflect the change I need ?
I would be grateful for any solution.

Comment: Your link is dead. Can you post a JSFiddle of your code?

Comment: Thanks McVenco. I had resolved the issue long ago.